# Spivak: Graph of convex $f$ lies above the tangent line...

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Calculus, 4th Edition: Michael Spivak, Chapter 11:

**Definition 2 (page 219):**

> A function $f$ is **convex** on an interval if for $a$, $x$, and $b$ in the interval with $a<x<b$ we have $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}<\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$.

**Page 221:**

> [...] if $h_2<h_1<0$, then $\frac{f(a+h_1)-f(a)}{h_1}>\frac{f(a+h_2)-f(a)}{h_2}$.

**My question:**

How do you derive a proof of this last inequality from the above definition?

Comment: Put $x=a+h_2$ and $b=a+h_1$.

Comment: @math-lover But $a+h_2 < a+h_1 < a$. So by your substitution, $x < b < a$. Which implies $\frac{f(a+h_2)-f(a+h_1)}{h_2-h_1}<\frac{f(a+h_2)-f(a)}{h_2}$. I don't see how to arrive at the given inequality from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\forall a, x, b \in I: a < x < b: \quad \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}<\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \quad \text{by definition}$$

$$\iff \quad \displaystyle \left({b - a}\right) f \left({x}\right) - \left({b - a}\right) f \left({a}\right) < \displaystyle \left({x - a}\right) f \left({b}\right) - \left({x - a}\right) f \left({a}\right)$$

$$\iff \quad \displaystyle \left({b - a}\right) f \left({x}\right) < \displaystyle \left({b - a - x + a}\right) f \left({a}\right) + \left({x - a}\right) f \left({b}\right)$$

$$\iff \quad \displaystyle \left({b - a}\right) f \left({x}\right) < \displaystyle \left({b - x}\right) f \left({a}\right) + \left({x - a}\right) f \left({b}\right)$$

$$\iff \quad \displaystyle \left({b - a}\right) f \left({x}\right) < \displaystyle \left({b - a - b + x}\right) f \left({b}\right) + \left({b - x}\right) f \left({a}\right)$$

$$\iff \quad \displaystyle \left({b - x}\right) f \left({b}\right) - \left({b - x}\right) f \left({a}\right) < \displaystyle \left({b - a}\right) f \left({b}\right) - \left({b - a}\right) f \left({x}\right)$$

$$\iff \quad \displaystyle \frac {f \left({b}\right) - f \left({a}\right)} {b - a} < \displaystyle \frac {f \left({b}\right) - f \left({x}\right)} {b - x}$$

$$\implies \quad \text{if} \quad h_2<h_1<0: \quad\displaystyle \frac {f \left({a}\right) - f \left({a+h_2}\right)} {a - (a+h_2)} < \displaystyle \frac {f \left({a}\right) - f \left({a+h_1}\right)} {a - (a+h_1)}$$

$$\implies \quad\displaystyle \frac {f \left({a}\right) - f \left({a+h_2}\right)} {-h_2} < \displaystyle \frac {f \left({a}\right) - f \left({a+h_1}\right)} {-h_1}$$

$$\implies \quad\displaystyle \frac {f \left({a+h_2}\right) - f \left({a}\right)} {h_2} < \displaystyle \frac {f \left({a+h_1}\right) - f \left({a}\right)} {h_1}$$

**Adapted from:** [Equivalence of Definitions of Convex Real Function](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Definitions_of_Convex_Real_Function)